# C++11 threads no matching function call

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am trying to make a threaded grabber for my OpenCV application. I am unable to figure out why this code doesn't compile. It gives me an error that I believe means that the function call is wrong. However, it is the exact same way how I start a thread using std::thread usually! I want to use std::thread to accomplish it because it will offer more platform-independent compatibility, so please don't tell me to use a platform-specific library. I also want this to be STL-based, so no Boost or DLib. In my main.cpp, I have a working thread application, the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#define read_failure_threshold 512
long grabbers_active = 0;

namespace dev
{
        class grabber
        {
        private:
        bool enabled = false;
        std::mutex lock;
        int capture_mode;
        int capture_id;
        unsigned long read_failures = 0;
        std::string stream;
        std::string grabber_name;
        cv::Mat image;
    public:
        void grabber_t()
        {
            .......[unimportant code]........
        }

        grabber(std::string name, int captureMode, int captureId, std::string location)
        {
            .......[unimportant code]........
        }

        void start()
        {
            if(!enabled)
            {
               std::thread grabber_thread(grabber_t);
               grabber_thread.detach();
            }
            enabled = true;
            grabbers_active++;
        }

        cv::Mat getImage()
        {
            .......[unimportant code]........
        }
    };
}


[ERRORS:]
In file included from /media/storage/programming/yash101/repos/Other/STL+OpenCV/threaded_grabber_template/main.cpp:1:0:
/media/storage/programming/yash101/repos/Other/STL+OpenCV/threaded_grabber_template/template.hpp: In member function ‘void dev::grabber::start()’:
/media/storage/programming/yash101/repos/Other/STL+OpenCV/threaded_grabber_template/template.hpp:119:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
                std::thread grabber_thread(grabber_t);
                                                    ^
/media/storage/programming/yash101/repos/Other/STL+OpenCV/threaded_grabber_template/template.hpp:119:52: note: candidates are:
In file included from /media/storage/programming/yash101/repos/Other/STL+OpenCV/threaded_grabber_template/template.hpp:4:0,
                 from /media/storage/programming/yash101/repos/Other/STL+OpenCV/threaded_grabber_template/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:133:7: note: std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (dev::grabber::*)(); _Args = {}]
       thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:133:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘void (dev::grabber::*&&)()’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:128:5: note: std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)
     thread(thread&& __t) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:128:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘std::thread&&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:122:5: note: std::thread::thread()
     thread() noexcept = default;
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:122:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/build.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/build.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The error log is also at the end of the code. The only errors I am worried about are the threading ones. The other ones are simple fixes, but require me to have the threading working.
I am in Ubuntu, using g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2. I have C++0x enabled in my CMakeLists.txt. Everything works perfectly in there

My main objective is to figure out why I am getting this error. I have been googling and trying different tricks for many hours, but nothing is working!

Thanks in advanced for your help :)

Comment: Do not alter you original code too much when posting it here. Compiler complains about `std::thread grabber_thread(grabber_t, this);` but in your code it is `std::thread grabber_thread(grabber_t);`.

Comment: I retried make and changed the output to what it currently happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change that :

```
std::thread grabber_thread(grabber_t);
```

Into that :

```
std::thread grabber_thread(&grabber::grabber_t, this);
```

---

`grabber_t` is a reference to non-static member function, you need to pass its address, but `&grabber_t` can't work as you must explicitly qualify name of member function when taking its address, thus resulting in `&grabber::grabber_t`.

Comment: That's neat how this change fixed my problem. However, why did my threading test program work properly without this?

Comment: When writing this, do you mean the C++ keyword `this` or do you mean the fix ?

Comment: I had tried this, but that hadn't fixed the problem initially. It was when I tried &grabber::grabber_t, when it actually started working!

Comment: Since you're passing a member function, you need both `&class_name::function_name` and `this`. Simply adding `this` won't alone help the compiler resolving the first argument.

Comment: I figured. My working example was in my main.cpp, just as two functions, not as a part of a class. This time, I had it as a part of a class, but being a slight newbie in C++ and classes, I didn't know what was causing this error